How to merge text in two columns so that each line matches in both text
I have a dataframe with two columns called microscopic_descriptionClean2 and cleaned_terms with the structure as follows:
The data
structure(list(cleaned_terms = c("\nPOT A body \nPOT B Antrum incisura body", 
"\nPOT A Stomach Oesophagus ", "\nPOT A Antrum         c\nPOT B incisura         c\nPOT C body        ", 
"\nPOT A  \nPOT B cardia cardia  cardia \nPOT E \nPOT  \nPOT G", 
"\nPOT A Antrum  Antrum \nPOT B"), microscopic_descriptionClean2 = c("POT A:\nPOT B:", 
"POT A:", "POT A: POT B and POT C IM", "POT A: IM", "POT A: IM"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

The problem
I would like to merge the columns so that a line with POT A for cleaned_terms  is merged with POT A in microscopic_descriptionClean2 and POT B in cleaned_terms with POT B microscopic_descriptionClean2 etc, in its own column.
Desired output
POT A: body POT A: 
POT B: Antrum POT B:
----------------------
POT A: Stomach Oesophagus POT A:
------------------------
POT A: Antrum POT A:        
POT B: incisura POT B         
POT C: body POT C IM
-----------------------
POT A: POT A: IM
POT B: cardia cardia  cardia
POT E:
POT :
POT G:
----------------------
POT A: Antrum  Antrum POT A: IM
POT B:
----------------------

My attempt
merge_text <- function(cleaned_terms, microscopic_descriptionClean2) {
  # Split cleaned_terms into POT and letter
  cleaned_pots <- gsub("[[:space:]]+", "", cleaned_terms)  # Remove extra spaces
  cleaned_pots <- grep("^POT [A-Z]$", cleaned_pots, value = TRUE, invert = TRUE)  # Remove empty entries
  
  # Split microscopic_descriptionClean2 into POT and content
  description_pots <- strsplit(microscopic_descriptionClean2, ":")[[1]]
  
  # Initialize result
  result <- character(max(length(cleaned_pots), length(description_pots)))
  
  # Merge text line by line where POT and letter match
  for (i in 1:length(cleaned_pots)) {
    if (cleaned_pots[i] %in% description_pots) {
      result[i] <- paste(cleaned_pots[i], description_pots[description_pots %in% cleaned_pots], collapse = ": ")
    } else {
      result[i] <- cleaned_pots[i]
    }
  }
  
  # Combine result into a single string with newlines
  merged_text <- paste(result, collapse = "\n")
  
  return(merged_text)
}

# Apply the function to create a new column in potmergednew
potmergednew$merged_text <- mapply(merge_text, potmergednew$cleaned_terms, potmergednew$microscopic_descriptionClean2, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

However this just merges all the lines in cleaned_terms and doesn't merge in the microscopic_descriptionClean2.

How should an entry like POT A: POT B and POT C IM be resolved, i. e. is only the "POT A" before the colon relevant, or should the join also consider "POT B" and "POT C"? That apart, you might find separate_rows(your_data_frame, cleaned_terms, sep = "\n") of {tidyr} useful.

If POT B and C are on the same line then should be considered as POT B only

Could you provide your desired output for the given sample

I'm not sure how the "POT B" line from the first row of the data you shared
matches the second line of your "Desired output" table, but here is a approach that relies on functions from the tidyverse package:
Original data, saved as pot_test:
structure(list(cleaned_terms = c("\nPOT A body \nPOT B Antrum incisura body", 
"\nPOT A Stomach Oesophagus ", "\nPOT A Antrum         c\nPOT B incisura         c\nPOT C body        ", 
"\nPOT A  \nPOT B cardia cardia  cardia \nPOT E \nPOT  \nPOT G", 
"\nPOT A Antrum  Antrum \nPOT B"), microscopic_descriptionClean2 = c("POT A:\nPOT B:", 
"POT A:", "POT A: POT B and POT C IM", "POT A: IM", "POT A: IM"
)), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame") -> pot_test

Cleaning of pot_test
library(dplyr)
pot_test |> 
  as_tibble() |> 
  rename(terms = 1, micro = 2) -> pot_test

pot_test
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   terms                                                                    micro
#>   <chr>                                                                    <chr>
#> 1 "\nPOT A body \nPOT B Antrum incisura body"                              "POT…
#> 2 "\nPOT A Stomach Oesophagus "                                            "POT…
#> 3 "\nPOT A Antrum         c\nPOT B incisura         c\nPOT C body        " "POT…
#> 4 "\nPOT A  \nPOT B cardia cardia  cardia \nPOT E \nPOT  \nPOT G"          "POT…
#> 5 "\nPOT A Antrum  Antrum \nPOT B"                                         "POT…

library(stringr)
pot_test |> 
  mutate(
    across(
      # apply anonymous function below to all columns
      everything(), 
      # convert 'and' and 'c' along with surrounding space into single space
      \(s) str_replace_all(s, '(\\s+[a-z]{1,3})*\\sPOT', ' POT')
      )
    ) -> pot_test

pot_test
#> # A tibble: 5 × 2
#>   terms                                                      micro              
#>   <chr>                                                      <chr>              
#> 1 " POT A body  POT B Antrum incisura body"                  POT A: POT B:      
#> 2 " POT A Stomach Oesophagus "                               POT A:             
#> 3 " POT A Antrum POT B incisura POT C body        "          POT A: POT B POT C…
#> 4 " POT A   POT B cardia cardia  cardia  POT E  POT   POT G" POT A: IM          
#> 5 " POT A Antrum  Antrum  POT B"                             POT A: IM

Extracting "POT" sections
library(tidyr)
pot_test |> 
  # replace space before 'POT' to underscore
  mutate(across(everything(), \(s) str_replace_all(s, '\\s+POT', '_POT'))) |> 
  # remove leading underscore and trailing space from terms columns
  mutate(across(terms, \(s) str_remove_all(s, '^_|\\s+$'))) |> 
  # split strings into POT sections; add row numbers first, to tag POT sections
  mutate(row = row_number()) |> 
  separate_longer_delim(terms:micro, '_') -> pot_test_long

pot_test_long
#> # A tibble: 13 × 3
#>    terms                       micro       row
#>    <chr>                       <chr>     <int>
#>  1 POT A body                  POT A:        1
#>  2 POT B Antrum incisura body  POT B:        1
#>  3 POT A Stomach Oesophagus    POT A:        2
#>  4 POT A Antrum                POT A:        3
#>  5 POT B incisura              POT B         3
#>  6 POT C body                  POT C IM      3
#>  7 POT A                       POT A: IM     4
#>  8 POT B cardia cardia  cardia POT A: IM     4
#>  9 POT E                       POT A: IM     4
#> 10 POT                         POT A: IM     4
#> 11 POT G                       POT A: IM     4
#> 12 POT A Antrum  Antrum        POT A: IM     5
#> 13 POT B                       POT A: IM     5

Extracting "POT" strings
pot_test_long |> 
  # extract POT string from each column
  mutate(
    across(
      terms:micro, 
      \(s) str_extract(s, 'POT( [A-Z])?'), 
      # use column names to name new columns
      .names = '{.col}_pot')
    ) -> pot_test_long

pot_test_long
#> # A tibble: 13 × 5
#>    terms                       micro       row terms_pot micro_pot
#>    <chr>                       <chr>     <int> <chr>     <chr>    
#>  1 POT A body                  POT A:        1 POT A     POT A    
#>  2 POT B Antrum incisura body  POT B:        1 POT B     POT B    
#>  3 POT A Stomach Oesophagus    POT A:        2 POT A     POT A    
#>  4 POT A Antrum                POT A:        3 POT A     POT A    
#>  5 POT B incisura              POT B         3 POT B     POT B    
#>  6 POT C body                  POT C IM      3 POT C     POT C    
#>  7 POT A                       POT A: IM     4 POT A     POT A    
#>  8 POT B cardia cardia  cardia POT A: IM     4 POT B     POT A    
#>  9 POT E                       POT A: IM     4 POT E     POT A    
#> 10 POT                         POT A: IM     4 POT       POT A    
#> 11 POT G                       POT A: IM     4 POT G     POT A    
#> 12 POT A Antrum  Antrum        POT A: IM     5 POT A     POT A    
#> 13 POT B                       POT A: IM     5 POT B     POT A

Combining corresponding "POT" strings
# use row values and POT strings to join terms and micro columns
pot_test_long |> select(!contains('micro')) |> 
  left_join(
    # remove redundant row-POT string combinations
    pot_test_long |> select(!contains('terms')) |> distinct(),
    by = join_by(terms_pot == micro_pot, row)
  ) |> 
  # replace NAs in micro column (introduced by left join) to empty strings
  replace_na(list(micro = '')) |> 
  # paste terms and micro columns together
  mutate(output =  str_c(terms, micro, sep = ' ')) |> 
  select(output, row, terms, micro)
#> # A tibble: 13 × 4
#>    output                                row terms                       micro  
#>    <chr>                               <int> <chr>                       <chr>  
#>  1 "POT A body POT A:"                     1 POT A body                  "POT A…
#>  2 "POT B Antrum incisura body POT B:"     1 POT B Antrum incisura body  "POT B…
#>  3 "POT A Stomach Oesophagus POT A:"       2 POT A Stomach Oesophagus    "POT A…
#>  4 "POT A Antrum POT A:"                   3 POT A Antrum                "POT A…
#>  5 "POT B incisura POT B"                  3 POT B incisura              "POT B"
#>  6 "POT C body POT C IM"                   3 POT C body                  "POT C…
#>  7 "POT A POT A: IM"                       4 POT A                       "POT A…
#>  8 "POT B cardia cardia  cardia "          4 POT B cardia cardia  cardia ""     
#>  9 "POT E "                                4 POT E                       ""     
#> 10 "POT "                                  4 POT                         ""     
#> 11 "POT G "                                4 POT G                       ""     
#> 12 "POT A Antrum  Antrum POT A: IM"        5 POT A Antrum  Antrum        "POT A…
#> 13 "POT B "                                5 POT B                       ""

Created on 2024-06-14 with reprex v2.0.2

I used strsplit() on the 2 columns to create 2 lists of character vectors. For each pair of elements of these lists, I made a function to convert them to data frames and join using dplyr::left_join(). (And also do a small bit of text cleaning). I used mapply() to run this function over all the strings and get a list of data frames in the required layout.
Finally I created one more function to convert this data frame to the text format of your required output.
Note: there are some extra "c" and "and" in your data which show up in my output. Your input may need some cleaning, or else just add some gsub() or stringr::str_replace() to the functions to clear these.
df <- structure(list(cleaned_terms = c("\nPOT A body \nPOT B Antrum incisura body", 
                                       "\nPOT A Stomach Oesophagus ",
                                       "\nPOT A Antrum         c\nPOT B incisura         c\nPOT C body        ", 
                                       "\nPOT A  \nPOT B cardia cardia  cardia \nPOT E \nPOT  \nPOT G", 
                                       "\nPOT A Antrum  Antrum \nPOT B"), 
                     microscopic_descriptionClean2 = c("POT A:\nPOT B:", 
                                                     "POT A:", "POT A: POT B and POT C IM",
                                                     "POT A: IM", "POT A: IM")),
                row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

library(dplyr)

# split cleaned_terms and microscopic_descriptionClean2 into 2 lists of character
# vectors
ct_split <- strsplit(df$cleaned_terms, "(?<!^)\\s(?=POT)", perl=TRUE)
md_split <- strsplit(df$microscopic_descriptionClean2, "(?<!^)\\s(?=POT)", perl=TRUE)

# Function to join corresponding elements of this list into data frames with
# cleaned and micro columns
combine_items <- function(cleaned, micro) {
  # data frame with cleaned terms and pot as id variable
  x <- data.frame(cleaned =  gsub("(POT [A-Z]?):?", "\\1:", cleaned)) %>%
    mutate(
      pot = gsub(".*(POT [A-Z]).*", "\\1", cleaned),
      cleaned = gsub("\n", "", cleaned)
    )
  
  # data frame with microscopic descriptions and pot as id variable
  y <- data.frame(micro = gsub("(POT [A-Z]?):?", "\\1:", micro)) %>%
    mutate(
      pot = gsub(".*(POT [A-Z]?).*", "\\1", micro),
      micro = gsub("\n", "", micro)
    )
  
  # join these together to create one data frame
  output <- x %>%
    left_join(y, by = "pot") %>%
    select(cleaned, micro)
  
  # replace NA with blank character value
  output[is.na(output)] <- ""
  return(output)
}

# create list of data frames
list_of_dataframes <- mapply(combine_items, ct_split, md_split, SIMPLIFY = FALSE)

# function to combine each row of the data frame into a string and
# then combine these values into a single string with line breaks
make_string <- function(data) {
  paste(data$cleaned, data$micro) %>%
    paste(collapse = "\n")
}

# finally apply this function to 
result <- paste(lapply(list_of_dataframes, make_string), collapse = "\n----------------------\n")
cat(result)
#> POT A: body  POT A:
#> POT B: Antrum incisura body POT B:
#> ----------------------
#> POT A: Stomach Oesophagus  POT A:
#> ----------------------
#> POT A: Antrum         c POT A:
#> POT B: incisura         c POT B: and
#> POT C: body         POT C: IM
#> ----------------------
#> POT A:   POT A: IM
#> POT B: cardia cardia  cardia  
#> POT E:  
#> POT :  
#> POT G: 
#> ----------------------
#> POT A: Antrum  Antrum  POT A: IM
#> POT B:

Created on 2024-06-14 with reprex v2.1.0
